# Ruby on rails não grava no banco

Tags: banco-de-dados, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

Boa noite, galera!

Criei um pequeno form com dois campos e futuramente pretendo expandir esse form com mais um ou dois campos. Acontece que a inserção dos dados no sqlite não esta sendo feita, porém não dá nenhum erro.

A aplicação esta sendo desenvolvida para ser um to-do list.

Vocês podem, por gentileza me dizer possíveis motivos?

bem, eu tenho como model:

`class ToDoList < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :is_favorite, :name, :description
  has_many :tasks,  dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :member
end`

e como controller:

```
  class ToDoListsController < ApplicationController
    ...
     def new
        @todo_list = ToDoList.new

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @todo_list }
        end
      end
    ...
     def create
    @todo_list = ToDoList.new(params[:todo_list])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo_list.save
        format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo list was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @todo_list, status: :created, location: @todo_list }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
        end
```

Agradeço desde já!

> Edit

Notei que eu estava chamando o params errado, chamando-o de @todo_list e era @to_do_list. Serve como exemplo a falta de atenção!

Veleu pela atenção, galera.

Comment: Qual o conteúdo do método create da sua classe ToDoListsControler? É nesse método onde o objeto é salvo no banco de dados.

Comment: esqueci de por o create, vou editar rs. o create é: 

`def create
    @todo_list = ToDoList.new(params[:todo_list])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo_list.save
        format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo list was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @todo_list, status: :created, location: @todo_list }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end`

Answer (score 2):

Como falado pelo Bernado Botelho normalmente quando se aprende Rails um controller do Rails tem as seguintes ações:

### - Ação     - Descrição

- #index   - Mostra todos os registros
- #show    - Mostra apenas um registro
- #new     - Mostra formulário para novo item
- #create  - Cria o novo item
- #edit    - Mostra formulário para editar item
- #update  - Atualiza novo item
- #delete  - Mostra alerta sobre deletar um item
- #destroy - Deleta o item

Neste caso vimos a sua new que provavelmente foi implementada para criar um novo TodoList, contudo ele não persiste este TodoList.

Para fazer a persistência do TodoList no action Create (provavelmente, você pode ter outros) você vai dar no @todolist (tendo em mente que este é um objeto do Model TodoList e que está com os dados do formulário) o seguinte comando:

```
@todolist.save
```

Isso deve salvar a todolist no banco que você está utilizando.

Uma forma de testar isso fácil é:

No terminal digite:

```
rails console
```

Isso irá abrir o console do Rails, digite:

```
todo_list = ToDoList.new
todo_list.save
```

Feito isso você deverá ver uma query SQL sendo exibida na página (caso esteja usando um banco SQL), isso significa que ele tentou salvar (e se não tiver um ROLLBACK significa que ele salvou);